# Using Marketing Cloud Publication List for SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms, publicationlist

Is it really possible to use publication list for SMS?

AFAIK, there is this documentation saying "If the list is used for SMS, name your publication list with no spaces. Add information to the description that identifies this publication list is used for SMS." https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_create_publication_list.htm&type=5

But when I'm configuring a SMS send either via MobileConnect or Journey Builder, I don't see an option to select a publication list like I do for email messages.

So that's why I'm asking if it's really possible to use publication list for SMS.

I've never seen somebody doing that, and I can't find any example of this on the web.

My guess is that is an old feature that's currently retired, and they forgot to remove from documentations.